# Can I query a DVWP with javascript?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, data-view-web-part

Is it possible to query results in a data view web part with javascript? If so, how do you reference the DVWP in the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use it like any other HTML on your page.  Since you'd have control over the DVWP, it'd make sense to properly set IDs and classes for things you want to hook into on the client side when the DVWP is loaded.

And to further add, I've done this on numerous occasions where I get the DVWP to output the content I want in the format I want to utilize jQuery tools like jQuery UI.

Comment: @pirateEric...thanks for the reply.....could you possibly point me to a reference for learning how to do this? I am new to this....or provide an example please?

Comment: What does your dvwp output and what are you trying to do with javascript?

Comment: well the first scenario I would try is this calendar recurrence issue. I can create a current view which shows 'today's events', so I can create a web part that references that view (this seems to be the ONLY way I can get those My Start and My End times that SP creates for the events that occur that day whether they are recurring or not). So a simple use case to start is I would like to be able to query and filter that web part...plus a larger goal is learn how to do it for other uses. Like I said I am just starting out so I am sort of learning the context; greatly appreciate the help!!